# How to update screen after SetWorldPose in Gazebo v1.8.6

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am working on Gazebo v1.8.6 with ROS-Fuerte and PR2.

While I am running my robot, I manipulate some objects using 'gazebo::physics::Entity::SetWorldPose.'

My problem is the following; non-static objects are visually updated correctly after its' position manipulation. However, static objects are not visually updated (its' actual position is changed and there is contact on expected location.)

I can see this kind of situation 9 out of 10 simulations.

Is there any way to force to update screen except 'ConnectWorldUpdateBegin'?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3752/how-to-update-screen-after-setworldpose-in-gazebo-v1.8.6/) by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-07-23**:
it may be related to [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/676/camera-images-are-not-updated-when-moving) in gazebo. I've seen it before too, and happens to static models

**Comment by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on 2013-07-24**:
I am not sure whether it is same or not. But, it looks very similar. I have used Gazebo v1.4.6 and seen this problem. It happens randomly but so much frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'll mark this question as closed since more recent Gazebo version has this fixed.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0